# xfce4.8 ярлыки приложения на рабочем столе для всех пользователей

Tags: xfce, linux

Приветствую.

Суть вопроса. Каждому входящему в xfce пользователю показывается на рабочем столе стандартные иконки (home, file system, trash), хочу добавить туда еще одно приложение.

Вопрос - где хранится скелет рабочего стола, что устанавливается всем пользователям?

Comment: ~/.config/xfce4/desktop у меня в системе так,не факт,а вот это попробуйте :)

Comment: Это рабочий стол для конкретного пользователя.

Comment: значит в папке desktop должен быть файлик,может скрытый,так и не сказать сразу,не пользуюсь рабочим столом "(openbox)"

Comment: да не в ту сторону вы думаете. Нет еще никакой папки desktop, она создается когда пользователь первый раз логинится в систему. Меня инетерсует тот "скелет" на основе которого создаются все эти папки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/skel но этот каталог копируется только при создании домашнего каталога нового пользователя.

Ещё есть каталог /etc/xdg/autostart (не знаю точно поддерживает ли xfce этот стандарт), в этом каталоге собраны файлы в формате .desktop .Можно написать скрипт, который будет выполняться каждый раз при графическом входе в систему, если в этом каталоге создать соответствующий файл запуска.Подробнее смотрите [стандарты freedesktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/).

Comment: /etc/skel - пустой./etc/xdg/autostart - два десятка .desktop файлов.. не совсем то..

Comment: попробуйте скопировать туда какой-нибудь ярлык из меню (/usr/share/applications). Если будет автозапускаться, замените строку exec=... на путь к своему скрипту, а в скрипте можно сделать что хотите

Comment: Вы вероятно не поняли, что я хочу. Мне не нужен автозапуск приложений, мне нужно чтобы на рабочем столе у всех текущих и вновь заведенных пользователей, кроме иконок Home, File System, Trash были еще те, что я захочу.Т.е. я хочу заранее сформировать "скелет" этих ярлыков, чтобы он назначался всем по-умочанию (аналог Docs and Settings/All Users в виде)

Comment: Я вам как раз показываю путь, как это можно сделать. Прямого аналога Docs and Settings/All Users в линуксе нет.

Comment: нее) это костыль.. похожий костыль я сделал ранее - скрипт который создает юзеров, выставляет им переменные прокси, создает папки и прочую лабудень.. добавлю туда копирование в /home/user/Desktop нужных .desktop файлов.. но это все неверно..

Comment: Это стандарт, который поддерживается многими оконными менеджерами. В данном случае больше возможностей, скрипт будет выполняться, когда каталог Desktop уже создан, кстати он может называться по-другому в зависимости от локали и выбора пользователя. Имя этого каталога хранится в переменной окружения XDG_DESKTOP_DIR и устанавливается в ~/.config/user-dirs.dirsВот тут немножко описано как создаются эти каталоги: http://packages.debian.org/ru/sid/xdg-user-dirs, никакого копирования файлов из общего каталога не предусмотрено, только создание пустых каталогов.